# Conflicting script Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Would anyone now why this script is disabling my nav in webkit browsers

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".project").fadeTo(0,0);

$(".class1, .class2, .class3, .class4, .class5, .class6, .class7, .class8, .class9, .class10, .class11, .class12, .class13, .class14, .class15, .class16, .class17, .class18, .class19, .class20, .class21, .class22, .class23").hover(
    function() {
        $(".project").text(this.title).stop(true).fadeTo("normal", 1);
    }, function() {
        $(".project").fadeTo("normal", 0);
    });
```

});

```
//Nav code

<li class="float-l"><?php echo get_nav_link('gallery', 4)?></li>
<li ><?php echo get_nav_link('philosophy', 6)?></li>
<li class="float-r"><?php echo get_nav_link('contact', 12) ?></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use "No Conflict" mode for WordPress based scripts.

You can switch `$` to `jQuery`

or put in into the ready.function like so.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
     .....
    });
```